# shorten encodeURIComponent(document.title)

Tags: javascript, onclick, window.location

I'm using `onclick="window.location.href"` as part of a `mailto` link and I wanted to know if there is a way to restrict the document title to a specific length. More specifically, our tab titles have `|` and I would like to end the subject line at the first `|`. Here is the code I'm using.

```html
<a style="color:#b9b9b9" href="mailto:?subject=&body=:%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.taconic.com" title="Share this page" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:?subject=Check out this page:%20' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + '&body=' +  encodeURIComponent(document.URL); return false;"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More specifically, our tab titles have | and I would like to end the subject line at the first |.

Replace `document.title` with the following:

```
document.title.replace(/^([^|]+)\|.*$/, '$1')
```

In the code above we use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The first argument is a regular expression, where

- the first `^` character stands for the beginning of the line;
- `[^|]` is a set of all characters, except the `|` character;
- `\|` is the `|` character escaped with backslash to distinct from the "OR" expression syntax;
- `.*` means any character(the dot) repeated zero or more times(the star);
- `$` character stands for the end of the line.

The second argument is the replacement string, where `'$1'` points to the first group in the regular expression(parentheses).

In other words, the code extracts all characters from the beginning of `document.title` until the `|` character.

You can make the string even shorter with [`String.prototype.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), for example:

```
document.title.replace(/^([^|]+)\|.*$/, '$1').substr(0, 20)
```

The `substr` method in the code above substracts 20 characters from the beginning of the result returned by the `replace` method. We *chain* the `substr` call, because the `replace` method returns a `String`.

Comment: PERFECT! All of what you wrote made sense - thanks! I'm not convinced I would have every gotten there but I got it now and that's all that matters.